# Android bracket errors

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm getting Bracket errors I just cant figure out.

the code should have a random number after a button is pushed, then I should have a counter that counts up below that. my goal in the end is to have a win condition that checks to see if the numbers are the same and you win. But just need help getting theese brackets to align right.
doing this in Eclipse for android
any help would be awesome thank you!

```
package com.viralgamez.gastime;

import java.util.Random;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class NewGame<Stopwatch> extends Activity {

    private TextView displayRandInt;
    private Button updateRandInt;
    final int MSG_START_TIMER = 0;
    final int MSG_STOP_TIMER = 1;
    final int MSG_UPDATE_TIMER = 2;

    private static final Random rand = new Random();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.newgame);

        /* Setup your Activity */

        // Find the views (their id's should be specified in the XML layout file)
        displayRandInt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.displayRandInt);
        updateRandInt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.updateRandInt);

        // Give the Button an onClickListener
        updateRandInt.setOnClickListener(new android.view.View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int randInt = rand.nextInt(100)+1;
                displayRandInt.setText(String.valueOf(randInt));
            }

            public void onClick2(View v) {
                if(status == false)
                {       
                    btnStart.setText("Stop");
                    status = true;        
                    new Thread(new Runnable()
                    { run(){
                          for(int i=0; i < 500; i++)
                          {
                              runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
                                    {
                                        @Override
                                        public void run()
                                        {
                                            txtCounter.setText(String.valueOf(i));
                                        }
                                    });
                               Thread.sleep(1000);
                          }}
                    }).start();

                }
                else if (status == true)
                {

                    btnStart.setText("Start");
                    status = false;
                    initCouner();
        });
```

Comment: Not sure what the question is; using consistent indentation would help a lot.

Comment: What is the exact error you get?

Comment: Multiple markers at this line
 - Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody
 - Syntax error, insert "else Statement" to complete 
  IfStatement
 - Syntax error, insert "}" to complete MethodBody
 - Syntax error, insert "}" to complete MethodBody

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I first ran your code through http://jsbeautifier.org/ (for JavaScript, but it indents Java just fine). You can do this in Eclipse using <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>. If you do this each time you add a new code block, your code will always be neat and tidy.

From there, it's easy to see which brackets match up. First, it's important to make `run()` into an actual method signature. Aside from that, you have an issue with the `else if` ending bracket.

I've transliterated your code from the auto-indenter, plus added the missing brackets at the bottom. I've commented in a few places that you should be looking out for (the method signature and missing brackets, namely).

```
package com.viralgamez.gastime;

import java.util.Random;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class NewGame<Stopwatch> extends Activity {

    private TextView displayRandInt;
    private Button updateRandInt;
    final int MSG_START_TIMER = 0;
    final int MSG_STOP_TIMER = 1;
    final int MSG_UPDATE_TIMER = 2;

    private static final Random rand = new Random();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.newgame);

        /* Setup your Activity */

        // Find the views (their id's should be specified in the XML layout file)
        displayRandInt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.displayRandInt);
        updateRandInt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.updateRandInt);

        // Give the Button an onClickListener
        updateRandInt.setOnClickListener(new android.view.View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int randInt = rand.nextInt(100) + 1;
                displayRandInt.setText(String.valueOf(randInt));
            }

            public void onClick2(View v) {
                if (status == false) {
                    btnStart.setText("Stop");
                    status = true;
                    new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        // run() { // This needs to be changed to an actual method signature
                        public void run() {
                            for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
                                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        txtCounter.setText(String.valueOf(i));
                                    }
                                });
                                Thread.sleep(1000);
                            }
                        }
                    }).start();

                // } else if (status == true) { // Change this to just }else{
                } else {

                    btnStart.setText("Start");
                    status = false;
                    initCouner();
                // }); // This needs to be changed to the following:
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be missing the bracket from the end of the `else if`, and another closing bracket for `onClick2` (Sam caught the second one before me)

Comment: I get a error on  
`private static final Random rand = new Random();`
and the last
`});`
I tried closing the Else if but just creates more stynx errors

Comment: What does the error say? Is that the bracket error?

Comment: @Dexter1088 is what you posted the entire code? Because if it is, then the problem is that you are missing a lot of closing brackets, not just the one for the `else if` and `onClick2`

Comment: Multiple markers at this line
 - Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody
 - Syntax error, insert "else Statement" to complete 
  IfStatement
 - Syntax error, insert "}" to complete MethodBody
 - Syntax error, insert "}" to complete MethodBody

Comment: Ok, so after you put in the two brackets after the code in the `else if`, so that it looks like Sam's answer, you're going to need two more brackets after the `});`, like fudge22it's answer. The last two are for `onCreate` and `class NewGame`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
updateRandInt.setOnClickListener(new android.view.View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
    }

    public void onClick2(View v) {
        if(status == false)
        {       
        }
        else if (status == true)
        {
        } // Not Here );
    }
}); // Here
```

And you are missing a few close brackets after this.

Comment: that causes errors everywhere. lol brackets are frustrating when you combine code from tutorials.

Comment: well there's your first problem... read tutorials and then write your own code.

Comment: @Dexter1088 I believe this solves the bracket problem using the code you posted. There are probably more that you haven't posted... and I'm not sure what you intent to do with `onClick2()`, since I don't see it being called inside the `OnClickListener` and you will have alot of trouble calling a "specific" anonymous class later.

Answer (score 0):

As was mentioned earlier, you are missing the closing brackets and your closing `);` is out of place, which has been corrected below. If you are using eclipse, to easily fix this in the future, just add closing brackets at the bottom of the page and click next to them. Eclipse automatically highlights the corresponding open and close brackets. You can do this to correctly align your brackets and parentheses or to figure out if you have too many brackets or need to add another one.

```
            //starting from the last else if statement
            else if (status == true)
            {

                btnStart.setText("Start");
                status = false;
                initCouner();
            }
        }
    });
  }
}
```